# when the add event is fired in backbonejs?

Tags: backbone.js

When does the 'add' event gets fired in a collection?

I am in a notion that when i execute something like `app.mycollection.create(this.newAttributes());` the add event will be fired.

Actually i do this while initializing a view

```
window.app.mycollection.on('add',this.render,this)
```

So ideally, first there should be a post request (when i do a create) and then the get request (my render function fetches rows from backend). But in network console, i get the opposite. I first see a get request and then the post request.

This made me thought that 'add' event gets fired immediately after a call to create method without waiting for creation to be complete.

This thus fetches me old data without including the data that has just been created. 
Please shed some light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have executed `render` function immediately. Try update your code:

`window.app.mycollection.on('add', this.render, this)`

#### EDIT

[Take a look](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create)

> Creating a model will cause an immediate "add" event to be triggered
> on the collection, a "request" event as the new model is sent to the
> server, as well as a "sync" event, once the server has responded with
> the successful creation of the model. Pass {wait: true} if you'd like
> to wait for the server before adding the new model to the collection.